# Display image with URL from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, url, image

I am using this code to display image from URL, but it is not working,

```
<?php
     echo 'me'.'<br/>';


      $sql= 'SELECT url_imgsrch FROM p_url_imgsrch';
      $result   =   mysql_query($sql);
        echo $result;
       $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


      for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++){

        //calling rows
        echo '<td>';
```

//calling rows value for debugging purpose so that i can learn the process and check the output

```
         echo $row[$i].'<br/>';

echo '<img name="myimage" src="<?php echo $row[$i]; ?>" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />';

            echo '</td>';
            }

     ?>
```

The result is, I get alt text only, and image is not displayed. also, I get error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\wamp\www\demo\login\flashcard.php on
>   line 31

In my file
What I am trying is, to get 5 img url from database and display them in columns of a table..and what I guess is I am getting same img URL again and again...for 5 times..

Please give me guideline and tell me what I could be missing...

Comment: echo '<img name="myimage" src="imgwed/<?php echo $row[$i]; ?>" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />';      have tried this code too for the same purpose...while googling, i got this code and thought to try it, but still failed..

Comment: you cant put an echo function inside of an echo function.

Comment: echo '<img name="myimage" src="$row[$i]" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />'; this was the line 34

Comment: you cant use `$row[$i]` is the loop i wrote in the post below this one. you have to put the column name  `$row[column_name]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have never seen someone loop through a query that way,  i do it like this:

```
print "<table>";
$sql= 'SELECT url_imgsrch FROM p_url_imgsrch LIMIT 5';
$result   =   mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print '<tr>
            <td>
               <img name="myimage" src="'.$row[column_name_here].'" width="60" height="60" alt="word" />
            </td>
          </tr>';
    }
print "</table>";
```

change column_name_here to the name of the column which store the image file name

edit: changed `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_array`  <- that is why u got the same image all 5 times.

Comment: thanks.....  '.$row[column_name_here].'  i change source of image to this, and the first of 5 images displayed correctly, but remaining four are displaying an erro             Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\wamp\www\demo\login\flashcard.php on line 34 ....what to do now?

Comment: whats on line 34 of flashcard.php

Comment: or you can use : `while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    <?php
    echo 'me'.'<br/>';

    $sql= 'SELECT url_imgsrch FROM p_url_imgsrch';
    $result   =   mysql_query($sql);
    echo $result;
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);


    for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++)
    {
        //calling rows
        echo '<td>';
        //calling rows value for debugging purpose so that i can learn the process and check the output
        echo $row[$i].'<br/>';
        echo '<img name="myimage" src=' . $row[$i] . ' width="60" height="60" alt="word" />';
        echo '</td>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in D:\wamp\www\demo\login\flashcard.php on line 34     got this error, its not working bro...anyhow, thanks for guiding a new bee

Comment: a echo inside echo ? `'<img name="myimage" src=' . echo $row[$i] . '` ?

Comment: sorry, i am totally a new bee in all of this, and i am at very beginner level, that's why i used echo inside echo

Comment: meh my bad, copied his original code and forgot to remove the echo

Answer (score 0):

With `mysql_fetch_row()` your fetching the results one row at a time, since you only specified `url_imgsrch` in the `SELECT` statement, it will be an array with one single element, the value for `url_imgrch`. This is the reason for your error message. The `for()` loop tries to in turn read the first, second, etc up to fifth value of the array, which never gets updated with new information and always has only one element.

`mysql_fetch_row()` will return `false` when there is no more data to be read, you need to call it to fetch each new row of data, so what you want is to rewrite your code to something along the lines of this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT url_imgsrch FROM p_url_imgsrch';

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while (false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  echo '<td>';
  echo '<img name="myimage" src=' . $row[0] . ' width="60" height="60" alt="word" />';
  echo '</td>';
}
```

The first part is just as you've written, setting up the SQL query and fetching a resource pointer (`$result`) to with `mysql_query()`.
In the next part the `while()` loop will run for as long as `$row` is not `false`, updating `$row` with new data for each run of the loop. Since `mysql_fetch_row()` fetches an numerically indexed array, you want to retrieve `$row[0]`, it's the first (and only) column you requested in the SQL query. There are many ways of writing the `while()` loop, but this way quite common, and easy to read for other developers.

Comment: thanks to you dear @zrvan, got your point, and i am trying this code, also i got what i was missing, but i have many url address of images, but i require only 5 of them, how will i modify mysql_fetch_row function...please guide me through this

Comment: @NewBee This is not part of the `mysql_query()` function, but rather the SQL statement, use this SQL instead: `SELECT url_imgsrch FROM p_url_imgsrch LIMIT 5` and you'll never get more than five results.

Comment: @NewBee Sorry, getting tired :) I meant `mysql_fetch_row()` in the previous comment.

Comment: thanks, got your point and i am clear now..really thanks to all of you for helping and supporting me in learning..